# difference between last row and row meeting condition dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, summarize

This is probably easy, but in a grouped data frame, I'm trying to find the difference in diff.column  between the last row and the row where var.col is B The condition only appears once within each group. I'd like to make that difference a new variable using summarize from dplyr.

```
my.data<-data.frame(diff.col=seq(1:10),var.col=c(rep('A',5),'B',rep('A',4)))
```

I'd like to keep this in dplyr and I know how to code it except for selecting diff.col where var.col==B.

```
my.data%>%summarize(new.var=last(diff.col)-????)
```

Comment: You can do: `my.data %>%
      summarize(difference = last(diff.col) - diff.col[var.col == "B"])` -- are you saying you don't want this solution?

Comment: Perfect! I knew it was simple, i was just bashing my head against a wall trying to use filter. Thanks!